# Is there any information as to if DC dropping or "Rebooting" the DCEU?

Tags: dc, movie, dc-extended-universe

There are a lot of changes coming in the future DC films [Robert Pattinson playing Batman is just *one!*] But I'm uncertain where that goes in terms of timeline. Considering the success of **Aquaman, Wonder Woman, Shazam** and the upcoming **WW-1984,** it would *seem* that film universe is still active, currently.... but logic would dictate that Pattinson's Batman most likely *wouldn't fit* the space Affleck left. I've heard no plans to balance these differences out.

Similar to the snippets of info for Marvel's "Phase Four",  are there any known "official" plans for the DCEU's continuance from here?

Are there any plans at relaunching it with new Superman and Batman stories or actors, since the original actors have departed?

Is the new Flash movie going to continue from Ezra Miller's portrayal?

Are they going to continue with new actors, or just start from scratch?

does anyone know any details?

Comment: And what of _Cyborg?!?_

Comment: Cyborg is in the Doom patrol series, which it has been stated is in the same universe as the teen Titans. I don't know if it has been clarified yet if this is DCEU, Arrow Verse, or another universe all together.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, the DCEU will be rebooted in favor of the "DC Universe" (DCU)**, an upcoming media franchise and shared universe based on DC Comics characters. This was officially announced in October 2022, when Warner Bros. hired James Gunn and Peter Safran to lead the new venture and be the co-chairmen and co-CEOs of DC Studios, the rebranded DC Films division at Warner Bros. Gunn is a filmmaker who is best known for directing the *Guardians of the Galaxy* films for Marvel Studios as well as *The Suicide Squad* for DC Films, and Safran is a producer who has worked on several DC projects, such as *Aquaman*, *Shazam!*, and *The Suicide Squad*.

*The Flash* (2023), a DCEU film, will serve as a reset point for the new continuity, using the concept of the multiverse to explain the changes. The DCU will consist of theatrical films, HBO Max series, and animated features that will tell an overarching story across different media platforms.

The DCU’s *Chapter One: Gods and Monsters* will introduce new versions of Superman and Batman, played by different actors than their DCEU counterparts.

The first film in this new continuity will be *Superman: Legacy*, written by James Gunn and slated for release in July 2025. *The Brave and the Bold* will be the first DCU Batman film, featuring the Dark Knight and his son, Damian Wayne, the fifth Robin in the comics.

Meanwhile, *The Batman* films by Matt Reeves and the *Joker* films by Todd Phillips are not part of the DCU. They belong to a separate line of "DC Elseworlds" titles, which explore alternative scenarios and timelines for the DC characters.

Sources and more info at:

- [*DC Shocker: James Gunn, Peter Safran to Lead Film, TV and Animation Division (Exclusive)*. The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-news/dc-movies-james-gunn-peter-safran-to-lead-film-tv-division-1235248438/)
- [*Everything Announced During James Gunn and Peter Safran's Big DCU Reveal*. IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/everything-announced-during-james-gunn-and-peter-safrans-big-dcu-reveal)
- [*James Gunn DC Slate Announcement*. James Gunn's tweet](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1620468379672002565)
- [*DC Slate Unveiled: New Batman, Supergirl Movies, a Green Lantern TV Show, and More From James Gunn, Peter Safran*. The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-features/james-gunn-unveils-dc-slate-batman-superman-1235314176/)
- [*James Gunn Confirms “Elseworlds” Strategy Will Allow DCU to Co-Exist With ‘The Batman’ and ‘Joker’ Franchises*. Collider](https://collider.com/dcu-elseworlds-strategy-the-batman-joker/)

Comment: https://wegotthiscovered.com/movies/blue-beetle-director-clarifies-the-movies-place-in-dcu-canon-in-the-most-confusing-way-possible/

Answer (score 1):

The best answer right now is that we just don’t know and that in part is because DC doesn’t seem to know.

The critical and financial failures of the justice league and Batman vs Superman films made Warner Brothers rethink there plans and from what we can tell success of wonder woman, Aquaman and Shazam has led to them focusing on standalone movies rather then forcing crossovers on the public.

Currently the release plans are Birds of Prey and Wonder Woman 2 in 2020 there are no indicators of any crossover here.

2021 the Batman, suicide squad (confirmed reboot/re imagining), and black Adam.

Shazam 2, Aquaman 2 and the flash in 2022.

Given black Adam and Shazam have history there is a possibility for crossover with these films but it seems that Warner is doing a soft reboot, accepting the events of justice league happened but not directly continuing on those story arcs. Shazam at least confirmed there is a Batman and Superman in the dceu they may take a bold option and just change actor as marvel did with the hulk in the mcu, without rebooting the character.

The flash is not being recast nor are Shazam and wonder woman, as far as I am aware Dwayne Johnson is still plying black Adam so the dceu is certainly not being canceled, to date it has made just over 5 billion in revenue and Aquaman broke 1 billion so they have seen that when done right the franchise with these actors is worth money.

Crisis on infinite earths showed that the tv dceu does exist in parallel to the movie universe (grant gustin’s flash met Ezra Miller). So if any of the movie actors start to struggle they could slip through a crack in the universe to a successfully well written dc franchise easily ;).

In addition we have to coinsider the newly created Teen Titan's and Doom Patrol series, both of which I believe are meant to fit in the DCEU as opposed to the Arrow Verse in much the same way as Marvels TV shows are meant to compliment the wider MCU